# Problem based on Prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory

Past codechef problem (Solutions are  public)

Zach and Cody are playing a game. There are initially $N$ chips on a table. Zach starts the game making the first move. In each turn one has to choose a move from a set of moves. The set of moves consists of all the moves of removing $p^k$ chips from the table, where $p$ is any prime and $k$ is any non negative integer. The winner is the one to take the last chip. Can you decide who will win the game, assuming both the players follow a perfect strategy? If Zach wins, what will be the smallest possible number that he can remove in his first move?

I have a very weak idea for its solution which is divisibility  by 6 after having look at many solutions but I need a conceptual explanation. Please provide that to get this concept.

solution is if there are $n$ chips then

```
    if(n%6==0)
        Cody  wins
    else
        Zach wins the game and can choose minimum  n%6 chips in his first move.
```

Again sorry for poor English.

Comment: Can't you write any number as $pk$ with $p$ a prime and $k$ a non-negative integer? So just pick all chips and you win.

Comment: I can always take the last chip on the first move given these constraints.  Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $N$, then $k={N\over p}$.

Comment: (That solution would be appropriate for: "In each turn either player gets to take between 1 and 5 chips. Who wins?" in which case the winner depends on $n \bmod 6 \equiv 0$ or not.)

Comment: What happens if there is one chip left?

Comment: @Henry: If 1 chip is left the next will take it: $1=2^0$

Comment: With these combinatorial game theory puzzles, it's often much easier to explain why the given solution works than to see how to discover the solution from scratch.  Are you just looking for a proof that $n$ mod $6$ is the decisive factor?

Comment: @all ... sorry as i pasted this problem .. p^k was written as pk .. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1,2,\ldots,5$ are prime powers, $6$ and multiples of $6$ are not because they contain the different factors $2$ and $3$.
So starting with $n \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$ Zach removes $z$ chips with $z \equiv k \pmod 6$ and $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then Cody removes $6-k$ chips. Now the numbers of chips is again divisible by $6$.